# Data Extension read-access via Installed Packages Scope

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, installedpackage

With the new permission model for Marketing Cloud Installed Packages, there is a problem with the "Read"-Scope for Data Extensions.

If an installed package is granted the permission/scope "Data Extensions - Read" the API-Call fails with HTTP 403 "Forbidden".

How to provide read access to Data Extensions?

**Related documentation:**

- [Installed Packages Scope](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/data-access-permissions.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the '[Marketing Cloud API Permission Changes](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HWmq)' trailblazer group.

> The Data Extension read permission just grants access to the container, relationships, filters and shared DE folders. It has no impact on viewing or manipulating the actual data within a DE. The Data Extension write permission is what grants access to the data.
>
> We have raised this confusion with the team that owns Data Extensions. We do not have a timeline as to when/if a change will be made. I will ask that owning team to update the documentation in the mean time